# Does domain history affect indexing?

Tags: domains, search-engine-indexing

I bought this domain in March without knowing that it had some past records dating back to 2019. The Wayback Machine didn't show anything, but later I noticed some links in Search Console.

[image]

Semrush also recorded some keywords from that same year, but I couldn't find anything on the Wayback Machine.

All posts get indexed within a few days but then disappear later. I'm not sure where the issue lies or when Google will notice the original content.

[image]

**I would appreciate any tips on how to fix this issue. Additionally, any suggestions on how to confirm a domain's detailed history to avoid making such mistakes in the future would be greatly appreciated.**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, history can affect your indexing, but this is likely not whats happening here.  It is not uncommon for Google to temporarily index your page (fresh content - yum), then sort it later and drop/reposition it in its index.  This is a more likely explanation.

You may want to do find the backlinks associated with the URL and if they are not appropriate disavow them in the Google console.